# Visual Studio not supporting XSLT 2.0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xslt, c#-3.0, xslt-2.0

i am using visual studio 2010 . when running xslt2.0 in that getting below errors

> xsl:value-of/* ** is not yet implemented.
>
> 'xsl:result-document'** is not yet implemented.

can any one help me to reslove the above issues

Comment: How are you running this? Please post your code. Also short examples of the source XML and XSLT would help with answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use XSLT 2.0 you need to switch from XslCompiledTransform to an XSLT 2.0 processor like the .NET version of Saxon 9 or like AltovaXML or like XmlPrime. Microsoft's XslCompiledTransform is an XSLT 1.0 processor, even in .NET 4.5/VS 2012.

However the named XSLT processors mainly allow you to write code using XSLT 2.0, I don't think they integrate in VS 2010.